# How to generate html report from different python scripts in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: python, html, flask, jenkins-pipeline

I'm starting to make a new infrastructure for automation at my company.
The plan is to write building blocks with python and then run them with Pipeline, here is an example-

```
pipeline{
    agent{
        label "node"
    }
    stages{
        stage("prerequisites"){
            steps{
               step("clone from repo"){
                git clone ...
               }
               step("mount folders") {
                python3.7 mount.py
               }
               step("check diskspace"){
                    python3.7 check_diskspace.py
               }
            }
        }
        stage("install"){
            step("install company product"){
                python3.7 install.py
                }
            }
        }
        stage("test"){
            python3.7 testname.py
        }
        // and more stages
    }
}
```

I want to make an HTML report of these steps that will have for each step information if the job failed or ended successfully, and if it failed to show the output of python why this step failed.

I tried to search a project that someone did so I could learn from but didn't have success with that.

I need a suggestion about how to make this report. I thought to add in each *.py a writing to file with some default values, and in the end, another python file that reads from the written file and makes an HTML report from it probably with flask.

If there is a better practice or well-known industry why to do this, please let me know.

p.s I know that at the end of the Pipeline, I need to use the HTML-Publisher plugin, I'm asking what is the best way to make the report while running the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML reports are kind of outdated, i bet your company would love to see a visualizaiton like this generated by [Blue oceans plugin](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/26/introducing-blue-ocean/)

Thats more of an industry standard visualization of CICD pipeline. Executives love this view.
If you still looking for HTML report you can give `yattag` a try which should help you generate HTML files as you progress through the pipeline. Inject a css in the template and you are all set.

[image]